# javascript Пошаговое движение игрового ии

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр

Я сделал простенький игровой ии,код будет ниже.Суть в том что бы сделать им пошаговое движение,а не что бы они моментально проделывали ходы.Надо заменить цикл while на что то другое скорее всего,ну из всех мои других дурацких идей эта лучшая.Если понадобятся исходники других файлов или объяснение функция,я добавлю.(Суть моего ии в том что бы мобы шли на корды игрока пока у них не закончатся ходы,не знаю поможет это или нет)

```js
var stepEnemyBase = function(i,set){
 if(set == "y-"){
  updateMap("3",enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y);
  enemyList[i].y -= 1;
  updateMap(enemyList[i].type,enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y);
 }else if(set == "y+"){
  updateMap("3",enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y);
  enemyList[i].y += 1;
  updateMap(enemyList[i].type,enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y);
 }else if(set == "x-"){
  updateMap("3",enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y);
  enemyList[i].x -= 1;
  updateMap(enemyList[i].type,enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y);
 }else if(set == "x+"){
  updateMap("3",enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y);
  enemyList[i].x += 1;
  updateMap(enemyList[i].type,enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y);
 }
}
var stepEnemy = function(){
 for(var i = 1;i < enemyList.length;i ++){
  if(enemyList[i].status){
   enemyList[i].mana = 100;
   while(enemyStep != enemyList[i].step){
    enemyStep += 1;
    if(xHero == enemyList[i].x){
     if(yHero < enemyList[i].y){
      if(checkBlock("player",enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y - 1)){
       if(checkBlock("block",enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y - 1) && checkBlock("enemy",enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y - 1)){
        stepEnemyBase(i,"y-");
       }else if(checkBlock("block",enemyList[i].x + 1,enemyList[i].y) && checkBlock("enemy",enemyList[i].x + 1,enemyList[i].y)){
        stepEnemyBase(i,"x+");
       }else if(checkBlock("block",enemyList[i].x - 1,enemyList[i].y) && checkBlock("enemy",enemyList[i].x - 1,enemyList[i].y)){
        stepEnemyBase(i,"x-");
       }
      }else{
       damageHero(10,50,i);
      }
     }else if(yHero > enemyList[i].y){
      if(checkBlock("player",enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y + 1)){
       if(checkBlock("block",enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y + 1) && checkBlock("enemy",enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y + 1)){
        stepEnemyBase(i,"y+");
       }else if(checkBlock("block",enemyList[i].x + 1,enemyList[i].y) && checkBlock("enemy",enemyList[i].x + 1,enemyList[i].y)){
        stepEnemyBase(i,"x+");
       }else if(checkBlock("block",enemyList[i].x - 1,enemyList[i].y) && checkBlock("enemy",enemyList[i].x - 1,enemyList[i].y)){
        stepEnemyBase(i,"x-");
       }
      }else{
       damageHero(10,50,i);
      }
     }
    }else if(yHero == enemyList[i].y){
     if(xHero < enemyList[i].x){
      if(checkBlock("player",enemyList[i].x - 1,enemyList[i].y)){
       if(checkBlock("block",enemyList[i].x - 1,enemyList[i].y) && checkBlock("enemy",enemyList[i].x - 1,enemyList[i].y)){
        stepEnemyBase(i,"x-");
       }else if(checkBlock("block",enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y + 1) && checkBlock("enemy",enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y + 1)){
        stepEnemyBase(i,"y+");
       }else if(checkBlock("block",enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y - 1) && checkBlock("enemy",enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y - 1)){
        stepEnemyBase(i,"y-");
       }
      }else{
       damageHero(10,50,i);
      }
     }else if(xHero > enemyList[i].x){
      if(checkBlock("player",enemyList[i].x + 1,enemyList[i].y)){
       if(checkBlock("block",enemyList[i].x + 1,enemyList[i].y) && checkBlock("enemy",enemyList[i].x - 1,enemyList[i].y)){
        stepEnemyBase(i,"x+");
       }else if(checkBlock("block",enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y + 1) && checkBlock("enemy",enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y + 1)){
        stepEnemyBase(i,"y+");
       }else if(checkBlock("block",enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y - 1) && checkBlock("enemy",enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y - 1)){
        stepEnemyBase(i,"y-");
       }
      }else{
       damageHero(10,50,i);
      }
     }
    }else if(xHero > enemyList[i].x){//x +
     if(checkBlock("block",enemyList[i].x + 1,enemyList[i].y) && checkBlock("enemy",enemyList[i].x + 1,enemyList[i].y)){
      stepEnemyBase(i,"x+");
     }else if(checkBlock("block",enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y + 1) && checkBlock("enemy",enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y + 1)){
      stepEnemyBase(i,"y+");
     }else if(checkBlock("block",enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y - 1) && checkBlock("enemy",enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y - 1)){
      stepEnemyBase(i,"y-");
     }
    }else if(xHero < enemyList[i].x){//x -
     if(checkBlock("block",enemyList[i].x - 1,enemyList[i].y) && checkBlock("enemy",enemyList[i].x - 1,enemyList[i].y)){
      stepEnemyBase(i,"x-");
     }else if(checkBlock("block",enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y + 1) && checkBlock("enemy",enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y + 1)){
      stepEnemyBase(i,"y+");
     }else if(checkBlock("block",enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y - 1) && checkBlock("enemy",enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y - 1)){
      stepEnemyBase(i,"y-");
     }
    }else if(yHero > enemyList[i].y){//y -
     if(checkBlock("block",enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y - 1) && checkBlock("enemy",enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y - 1)){
      stepEnemyBase(i,"y-");
     }else if(checkBlock("block",enemyList[i].x + 1,enemyList[i].y) && checkBlock("enemy",enemyList[i].x + 1,enemyList[i].y)){
      stepEnemyBase(i,"x+");
     }else if(checkBlock("block",enemyList[i].x - 1,enemyList[i].y) && checkBlock("enemy",enemyList[i].x - 1,enemyList[i].y)){
      stepEnemyBase(i,"x-");
     }
    }else if(yHero < enemyList[i].y){//y +
     if(checkBlock("block",enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y + 1) && checkBlock("enemy",enemyList[i].x,enemyList[i].y + 1)){
      stepEnemyBase(i,"y+");
     }else if(checkBlock("block",enemyList[i].x + 1,enemyList[i].y) && checkBlock("enemy",enemyList[i].x + 1,enemyList[i].y)){
      stepEnemyBase(i,"x+");
     }else if(checkBlock("block",enemyList[i].x - 1,enemyList[i].y) && checkBlock("enemy",enemyList[i].x - 1,enemyList[i].y)){
      stepEnemyBase(i,"x-");
     }
    }else{
     console.log("Вы в другом пространстве!");
    }
   }
   enemyStep = 0;
   stopTimer = 3;
  }else{
   enemyStep = 0;
   stopTimer = 3;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте разбить на ф-ии, не больше 15-20 строк каждая.

Comment: Что именно нужно разбить на функции?Каждое движение?Если я правильно тебя понял то ничего не выйдет,у меня идёт проверка на то есть ли перед мобов блок,и если сделать как ты говоришь,то у меня проверка будет запоздалой.Пока он походит,проверка пройдёт пару раз,и если блока нету перед мобов,но он есть на блок дальше,то моб спокойно туда пройдёт,ибо он ещё на той стадии где блока перед ним нет

Comment: Все что можно разбить разбивайте. Так читать этот код мало кто будет.

Comment: И не ограничивайтесь одним разбиением. В вас много блоков с очень похожим кодом, имеет смысл вынести повторяющийся код в отдельную функцию, а все различия передавать как параметры этой функции.

Comment: Так я уже делал,но почему то решил вернуть всё назад.Это решить не проблема.Но как сделать что бы они ходили через время?

Comment: Укоротил код,что теперь делать?

Comment: Для движения откройте для себя как минимум `SetInterval` .... или [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame) - для того чтобы зациклить что-то...............при этом движение будет составлять например `dir * speed * deltaTime`, где `dir` - направление движения, `speed` - скорость и `deltaTime` - величина времени, сколько прошло со времени вызова прошлого кадра (вызова функции перерисовки)

Comment: У меня игра пошаговая,что то типа Герои меча и магии,двигаются они по клеткам.Мобам нужно подавать координаты,и по им они двигаются.Но цикл мне здесь нужен был только для того что бы моб ходил пока у него есть очки хода.Мне нужно сделать что бы они двигались через определённое время,но есть некоторые проблемы,а именно то что координаты постоянно меняются, и моб не успевает ходить по тем по которым нужно.Он уже идёт по новым.Я думал сделать что то типа очереди,но как это реализовать?

Comment: Вот [игра](http://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/677613).Может быть проще переписать ии полностью?

Comment: @edikxl `У меня игра пошаговая,что то типа Герои меча и магии` - не важно.......все игры построены так, что всегда крутится цикл перерисовки.....а объекты следуют командам..... грубо говоря у объекта есть флаг "ходить" в значении `false`.... есть функция `function move(step)` ..... она просто в какой-то момент вызывается, когда флаг "ходить == true" и все......а сама функция внутри той, что управляет кадрами....это если очень в грубой форме............. возможно что-то отсюда вам поможет: https://habrahabr.ru/post/184666/

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему с помощью задержки отрисовки. Мог бы по факту на месте, но для пользователя они только двигаются. Спасибо за наводку на мысль